# CodingBat maxBlock

Tags: java

I have been going through some codingbat exercises and I came across this problem. 
"Given a string, return the length of the largest "block" in the string. A block is a run of adjacent chars that are the same."
Required Output:

```
maxBlock("hoopla") → 2
maxBlock("abbCCCddBBBxx") → 3
maxBlock("") → 0
```

My code seems to pass all the test except for the last one "other test". Can someone please review my code and tell me where exactly I could have gone wrong.

Submitted Code:

```
   public int maxBlock(String str) {
      int charBlock = 0;
      int holder = 1;
      if(str.length() == 0){ //If string is empty return 0
         charBlock = 0;
      } else if(str.length() == 1){ //If string contains only a single char return 1
         charBlock = 1;
      } else {
          for(int i=0; i < str.length()-1; i++){   //loop through each char value
              if((str.length() == 2) && (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1))){ 
                  charBlock =1; //return 1 if the length of the string is 2 and non of the two chars match
              }   
              else if((str.length() == 3) && (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i+1))){
                 charBlock = 1; //return 1 if the length of the string is 3 and non of the three chars match
              } 
              else if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)){
                 holder = holder + 1; 
                   if(holder > charBlock){
                     charBlock = holder; //update the value of charBlock if a holder is larger current value
                     }
             } else holder = 1; 
          }
      }
      return charBlock;
    }

Expected    Run     
maxBlock("hoopla") → 2  2   OK      
maxBlock("abbCCCddBBBxx") → 3   3   OK      
maxBlock("") → 0    0   OK      
maxBlock("xyz") → 1 1   OK      
maxBlock("xxyz") → 2    2   OK      
maxBlock("xyzz") → 2    2   OK      
maxBlock("abbbcbbbxbbbx") → 3   3   OK      
maxBlock("XXBBBbbxx") → 3   3   OK      
maxBlock("XXBBBBbbxx") → 4  4   OK      
maxBlock("XXBBBbbxxXXXX") → 4   4   OK      
maxBlock("XX2222BBBbbXX2222") → 4   4   OK      
other tests                             X
```

Comment: I don't know what the last test test, but if it calls `maxBlock(null);`, it'll fail.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, which might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks @ZouZou. I don't know either what the last test is actually testing. Do you have any idea how I could resolve the issue for maxBlock(null); or help me understand why it fails?

Comment: Well if you pass `null`, what do you think `str.length()` will do? I suggest you to try.

Comment: @ZouZou Okay, I added if(str.equals(null)){ charBlock = 0; } to bypass that scenario.

Comment: @LawrenceBass That won't bypass anything. Try to think about it.

Comment: I tried it out with `if(str == null){ charBlock = 0; }` as my first main if statement and this gives me 0 when `maxBlock(null);` is called. @ZouZou

Comment: @LawrenceBass That's not possible. See http://ideone.com/yLGNrP

Comment: Sorry I sent you the wrong thing, I used `if(str == null){ charBlock = 0; }` , This is what worked for me @ZouZou

Answer (score 0):

This can be more efficient especially with a helper method! Don't overthink the problem, I know its hard. My strategy is get the block for this char and move on to the next one.

```
    public int maxBlock(String str) {
       if (str.length() == 0) {
           return 0;
       } 
       int biggest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
       for (int a = 0; a < str.length(); a++) {
           biggest = Math.max(biggest, (countBlock(str, str.substring(a, a + 1), a));         
       }
       return biggest; //by now we have the biggest
    }

    public int countBlock(String s, String any, int startIndex) {
       int cnt = 1;
       for (int a = startIndex + 1; a < s.length(); a++) { //start right after index
           if (s.substring(a, a + 1).contains(any)){ //keep going
              cnt++;
           }

           else if (!s.substring(a, a + 1).equals(any)) { //stop here
              break;
           }
       }
       return cnt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good but you are unnecessarily checking the length of the input string.
Here is your code with some improvements.

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
    int holder = 1;
    int charBlock = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < str.length()-1; i++){   //loop through each char value
       if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1)){
         holder++; 
      }else{
        holder = 1;
      }
      if(holder > charBlock){
         charBlock = holder; //update the value of charBlock if a holder is  larger current value
      }
    }
  return charBlock;
 }
```